# Getting "Could not get data: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'college'"

Tags: php

I am trying out following code:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
        include 'config.php';


        if (!$conn) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $sql = 'SELECT name, gender, age FROM student';
        mysql_select_db('college');
        echo $sql;
        //echo $conn[] ;
        $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

        if (!$retval) {
            die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            echo "Name :{$row['name']}  <br> " .
            "Gender : {$row['gender']} <br> " .
            "Age : {$row['age']} <br> " .
            "--------------------------------<br>";
        }

        echo "Fetched data successfully\n";

        mysql_close($conn);
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'college');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
#$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

if($conn === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

I am getting following error:

```
Could not get data: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'college'
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44463149/11686005) thread, I have run:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
```

in phpAdmin and it worked. But still getting same error.

If I remember this correct, I was able to work with `college` database using `root` user earlier, but now I am getting this exception. Whats going wrong here?

Comment: Do not use mysql use mysqli or direct PDO for an database connection.

Comment: I guess I have used `mysqli_connect`

Comment: That's weird, you clearly pass "root" as second parameter, but error message says user is ''@'localhost', i.e. username part is empty string. Can you double-check that part please? Maybe put literal value there instead of constant (just for testing).

Answer (score 1):

I know what's the problem.

In `config.php` you initialize connection with `mysqli_connect` -- note `i` after `mysql`.

But later you use `mysql_query`, no `i`. That's a different driver which tries to connect using default (empty) credentials. That's why you see empty username in error message.

So, to fix that, replace all `mysql_` functions with `mysqli_` versions.

Answer (score -1):

The `mysqli_connect()` function returns an object which you have to use to make calls to your database.

I.E.

```
include 'config.php';

// Make a connection
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pw, $db);

// Create query.
$sql = 'SELECT name, gender, age FROM student';

// Apply query.
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

For more information visit this link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php